# No suitable method found for Collections.sort()

Tags: java, interface, compareto

I am working through some of the examples to learn Java, and it seems that I am not able to use `Collections.sort` to sort my list. Currently, my codes are following:

```
// Person class in package application.domain

package application.domain;

public class Person implements Identifiable, Comparable<Identifiable> {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    // ...Constructor...

    // ...Accessors for getName and getPersonID...

    @Override // from interface "Identifiable"
    public String getID(){
        return getPersonID();
    }

    public int compareTo(Identifiable another) {
        return this.getID().compareTo(another.getID()); 
    }

    //... toString ...

}
```

```
// Register class implementation

package application.domain; 
import java.util.*;

public class Register {
    private HashMap<String, Identifiable> registered;

    // ...Constructor - initialize hashmap ...

    public void add(Identifiable toBeAdded){
        this.registered.put(toBeAdded.getID(), toBeAdded);
    }

    // get
    public Identifiable get(String id){ return this.registered.get(id); }

    // getAll - must be generalized to work
    public List<Identifiable> getAll(){
        return new ArrayList<Identifiable>(registered.values());
    }

    // sortAndGetEverything (ERROR)
    public List<Identifiable> sortAndGetEverything(){
        List<Identifiable> all = new ArrayList<Identifiable>(registered.values());
        Collections.sort(all); // <- part of code that gives an error
        return all;
    }
}
```

with following output:

[image]

*Note that comments with ellipses are used to abbreviate irrelevant parts

What I am suspecting is the Person class's `toCompare` may be the problem since it is comparing the String... however, I looked it up online and it seems that comparing two different strings are valid with `.compareTo` method. I tried converting ArrayList to List and still have the same error. I am out of idea so I would like to not if anyone have any suggestion on fixing this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The single-argument version of `Collections.sort()` requires a list of objects extending `Comparable`. It seems your `Identifiable` class does not satisfy this requirement

Comment: can you show us your `Identifiable` class/interface?

Comment: It is worth noting that the compilation error message says what is wrong.  Unfortunately you decided to give us only a screenshot of the error message rather than the actual text.  So we cannot copy-paste it into an answer to explain it to you.  Too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `Identifiable` interface from `Comparable`:

```
public interface Identifiable extends Comparable<Identifiable> {
    String getID();  
}
```

Now you dont need to implement Comparable in `Person` class as well, and Collections.sort() should work now

Comment: FYI, OP's `Identifiable` is an interface. It only needs to extend `Comparable`

Comment: Thank you! my interface class were similar to yours except that I needed to add ```extends Comparable<Identifiable>``` on top of what I had.

Answer (score -1):

You can just add one line in the first java file:

```java
import java.lang.*
```

I meet the same error as you and I solved it by the solution mentioned above. I think the reason why it happens is that the complier don't recognize the cumtomer compareTo function.

Comment: It should never be necessary to import `java.lang.*`.  The classes in that package are auto-imported on demand.  (And besides, something not being imported is not the cause of the problem in this question.  The accepted answer is the correct solution ...)